# How to define routes while creating magento custom rest api's

Tags: api, rest, magento

I want to create custom rest api in magento, I tried calling it using tutorials available, but some how i am only able to call `_retrieve` and `_retrieveCollection` method only using GET.

So what I want to know how to create routes in **api2.xml**, so that i can call all the functions defined like:

- _create
- _retrieve
- _delete
- _update
- _retrieveCollection
- _multiCreate
- _multiUpdate
- _multidelete

and also want to know, when to use GET, POST, PUT and DELETE.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> So what I want to know how to create routes in api2.xml

Those other functions permissions are defined by the existence of for example `<create>1</create>` under the privileges for the role you want to use.

Once you've defined the privileges for your role(s), the routes depend on each type.

The easiest way (since the Magento API is not well referenced if you're adding your own things to it) is to look at existing core Magento code to see how they do it.

For example:

- `_create()` is handled by the same endpoint as `_retrieveCollection()`, just use POST instead of GET. `route_collection` route. `_create()` uses the `create` privilege, while `_retrieveCollection()` uses the `retrieve` privilege.
- `_retrieve()` is a GET request, defined as the `route_entity` route given the `retrieve` privilege
- `_delete()` is a DELETE request to an entity endpoint (`route_entity`), given the `delete` privilege is granted

For multi examples, take a look for existing core code examples, e.g.  `_multiCreate()`: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Api2_Product_Website_Rest`.